# WPF: style doesn't get applied to Window subclass

Tags: wpf, xaml

This problem has been driving me crazy for a full day now! Please help!

In a blank test app, I created a subclass of System.Windows.Window and applied a style to it in a resource dictionary, and it worked fine.

Now I'm doing the same in my actual app, and everything builds and runs - but the style is not applied to the window!

I narrowed things down to just trying to make the window background red... this simply doesn't work and I'm pulling hairs out!

PropertiesWindowBase.cs:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace MyApp.Client.UI.Windows
{
    public class PropertiesWindowBase : Window
    {
    }
}
```

Styles.xml:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:windows="clr-namespace:MyApp.Client.UI.Windows">
<Style TargetType="{x:Type windows:PropertiesWindowBase}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
</Style>
```

App.xml:

```
<Application x:Class="MyApp.Client.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         Startup="App_OnStartup">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

App.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;

namespace MyApp.Client
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        private void App_OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            var window = new CaseUserPropertiesWindow();// { DataContext = vm };
            window.ShowDialog();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

CaseUserPropertiesWindow.xaml:

```
<windows:PropertiesWindowBase x:Class="MyApp.Client.UI.Windows.CaseUserPropertiesWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:windows="clr-namespace:MyApp.Client.UI.Windows"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="CaseUserPropertiesWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
</windows:PropertiesWindowBase>
```

CaseUserPropertiesWindow.xaml.cs:

```
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for CaseUserPropertiesWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class CaseUserPropertiesWindow : PropertiesWindowBase
    {
        public CaseUserPropertiesWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: TargetType denotes the most derived type. Hence it should be CaseUserPropertiesWindow instead of PropertiesWindowBase. You may have a Style for CaseUserPropertiesWindow that is `BasedOn` the Style for PropertiesWindowBase.

Comment: THANK YOU @Clemens. I think I finally understand it now: So a style will only be applied to the most derived type, not to the base type - unless the base class has a static constructor that calls DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata? And then the style MUST be in Themes\Generic.xaml? am I right?

Comment: Do you want to write this as an answer so that I can choose this as a solution? Or should I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TargetType` denotes the most derived type. Hence it should be `CaseUserPropertiesWindow` instead of `PropertiesWindowBase`.

You may have a Style for CaseUserPropertiesWindow that is `BasedOn` the Style for PropertiesWindowBase:

```
<ResourceDictionary ...>
    <Style TargetType="windows:PropertiesWindowBase">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>

...

<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    <Style TargetType="local:CaseUserPropertiesWindow"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type windows:PropertiesWindowBase}}">
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for.